# how do you write the grad operator?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

I can only get `\div` which is upside down. I tried typing `\grad` but no luck. Packages I am using:

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
```

Comment: It is called `\nabla`.

Comment: that worked why don't you make an answer of it ?